# memoryerror on python imaplib when fetching an email

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7.15+ on ubuntu server, here is my code

```
piece, messrow = imap.uid('fetch',id,'(RFC822)')
email_message = email.message_from_string(messrow[0][1])
```

The error

```
File "/var/www/mail.py", line 91, in <module>
    email_message = email.message_from_string(messrow[0][1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.py", line 56, in message_from_string
    from email.parser import Parser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
MemoryError
```

This happens with small messages as well.
The machine has 4G ram, I knew that python does not have a memory limit apart from the available machine memory.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Note that the "available machine memory" is shared with all other processes, starting with all the OS stuff. Also, your system doesn't necessarily allows you (or more exactly "the user account under which this code is running") to use that much memory (this can be limited with ulimits or similar tools). And finally, two lines of code don't tell much about the context - you might just have built a humongous list or dict or whatever previously which is eating all your ram already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was a problem that I solved by increasing the machine memory :)